# assigning width of an element same as the content string's width

Tags: css

I've the mark up

```
<div id="name" class="width200">
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="inputName"  />
</div>
```

The value of the input item is generated dynamically and the length may differ. Now I want to use

```
#name {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

so that the `#name` is center aligned; and for that I need to assign the proper width for the div (If I don't assign anything, it acts like 100%). Since the input value is dynamically generated, I can't just assign a fixed value.

How do I make it sure that the width of the iv `#name` is automatically assigned to fit the content?

Comment: `width: auto;` didnt worked???

Comment: what do you have inside that `<div>` ? if it's only a text you can use `align: center;`

Comment: That won't work, you need to specify a width on the #name so that it can be centered. Or maybe put the input in display:block ans center it inside de #name.

Comment: I tried auto but it acts like 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the DIV to `display:inline-block;width:auto` or `display:inline;width:auto`.

You could also try doing what lipelip said in a comment on another answer here: set the DIV to `text-align:center`, which will stretch it and center its contents within it.